# Is it valid for an answer to berate the reader for not knowing something simple?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, etiquette

While browsing Reddit, I landed on this thread: [shit, they found out!](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/wp0v64/oc_shit_they_found_out/), about this Stack Overflow question: [What does \d+ mean in regular expression terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841550/what-does-d-mean-in-regular-expression-terms)

The answer there uses a condescending tone to berate the reader for not knowing something simple. Here is the quote from the answer:

> This is about as simple as regular expressions get. You should try reading up on regular expressions a little bit more. Google has a lot of results for regular expression tutorial, for instance.

My question is, is this valid text for a Stack Overflow answer? In my view the answers should only provide a solution to the question, and no criticism, but since the post is highly voted, I am hesitant to edit it myself.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it can be considered rude or impolite,  however, I agree that it is "noise"

Comment: In 2010 Twitter was still un-important and the welcoming wagon was 6 to 8 years away. Back then you could have a very Dutch approach to answers. Not anymore today. Edit to make it fit for consumption by a twelve year old. Wake-up the educator in you.

Comment: i mean, they're not wrong (but also it's not relevant)

Comment: @KevinB: You are absolutely correct, it is not wrong at all. But if I Google to land on a Stack Overflow answer, I want the answer, not to be told to Google again.

Comment: I'm trying to restrain myself from writing an answer saying "This is about as simple as a Meta Stack Overflow question gets. We've had questions on Meta about what to do with rude text in posts for years. Edit it or flag it."...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: That is hilarious. :) But the thing is, the answer has 129 upvotes, and it is a top search result for `\d+ regex`, so an edit would need some extra consideration in my opinion. Hence the question.

Comment: "Berate" is the wrong approach, but you can at least *downvote* to reflect the lack of research. (Note that lack of *research* is different from lack of *knowledge* - the former can often be solved with a search engine, the second could well require a new post on SO)

Comment: @user000001 Meh. I've edited posts with that many votes. I mean, if they spell something wrong, the upvotes don't make the spelling correct... Ditto with rudeness. They edited the [in]famous answer to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593) and that had more votes.

Comment: Votes shouldn't matter, when editing a question. Unless the edit itself is controversial, you are free to make any helpful edit which improves the post.

Comment: So the consensus seems to be that it should be edited out. I'll wait for a few hours in case a conflicting opinion arises, otherwise I'll edit it out myself. Thank you all for the input.

Comment: That quote is neutral & helpful. But in an answer it's noise.

Comment: Looks like someone else [got to the edit first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2841557/revisions); I feel like they did a great job of keeping it helpful while removing anything that could _possibly_ be read as malintent, even given the mild tone that was already there. As edited, it remains a useful addition to the answer imo.

Comment: *"You should try reading up on regular expressions a little bit more."* is clearly [RTFM](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RTFM#Phrase). RTFM is never ever acceptable. Remove the slightest hint of it on sight. Stack Overflow is not about users anyway. In many cases the best course of action is to point to the canonical question (in the right (neutral) tone—e.g., rhetorical questions should be avoided). It is not that important if the question is actually closed or not as long as the information is available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### This sort of rhetoric should be edited out of answers

At best, it's unhelpful noise.  Sometimes, these questions become the search result that people find when they look for the answer in the future.  **Remember, we're answering questions for the next person with the same problem**.

Tutorials are pretty terrible when your goal is to find an answer to something specific: you generally have to read many pages of irrelevant information.  Stack Overflow is great for this: you jump straight to the answer to your one specific question.

Consider the case of a person who's maintaining an existing system, is new to regex, and just needs to understand a one-off `\d+` regex in some code that's finding numbers.  Is it better for them to spend hours reading a regex tutorial to learn regex fully, or five minutes searching for and reading a Stack Overflow answer that contains *just* what they need to know?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I completely agree with you. But what do you think about [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2841557/revisions) (not by me), that tones down the rhetoric, while preserving the original message. Is the edit good, or should the entire sentences be removed, as other commenters have suggested?

Comment: @user000001 In my opinion, the edit should have gone further and removed the link to a web search for tutorials.  I've edited it further to try to preserve the useful parts of the advice and update it for the modern era in which there are online tools that do this too.

Comment: Somewhat tempted to add to this answer something along the following lines: "If this was not already obvious to you, you should familiarize yourself with [Stack Overflow's goal](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [our Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)."

Comment: I wouldn't say it is unhelpful entirely, but it is the act of trying to teach (or more to the point: lecture). And that is not what Stack Overflow is for. It is a clear case of someone needing to learn to contain themselves - the author of the answer that is.

Answer (score 1):

No, is this not a valid text for a Stack Overflow answer.

In my work in some of the largest US tech companies over nearly 30 years, I have many times witnessed these types of flippant emails.  They are not only un-helpful, they are purposefully harmful.  In successful start-ups people who write/say such things are quickly removed.  Successful professionals quickly leave environments where such things are tolerated.  The onus is upon managers to handle this -- refer to The No Ass Hole Rule. (of course actual, idiots are removed as well, but not as fast)

A better way to address a "stupid question" (in school, I was told these do not exist), is to explain why it is stupid, doing this along with the actual answer seems to me to be appropriate, but often the answer is not embedded in such flippant replies.  This equates to wasted time for the writer and readers (I'm guessing the writer does not consider that the aggregate time to read could be much greater than the time to write/spew his/her/its flippancy).  In the case being discuss here, the answer was included--for me, that would be enough to quell my anger if I was the asker.

Another thing I have noticed over the years is that many times there are subtle aspects/contexts/etc. that are missed by the flippant answerer.  These aspects/contexts often make these seemingly "stupid/simple questions" very interesting/complex.

Ideally, "take it off-line".  If the system allows it, talk to the asker privately and nicely somehow rather than humiliate someone.

Or just "keep your mouth shut".